# Proof to theory - Let x be subset of G. There is a group generated by x which is the intersection of all subgroups of G containing x.

Tags: linear-algebra

Im trying to prove theory:
Let x be subset of G. There is a group generated by x which is the intersection of all subgroups of G containing x.

Its not easy for me to do this at all.
I tried many different routes but they seem to go nowhere.
Thanks in advance for anyone who is able to help me proving that theory.

Comment: Isn't this the definition of a generator. Is the question to show that the generator exists and/or that it is a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that's helpful to notice is that, if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of some group $G$, then so is $A\cap B$.

(you can skip down to the next paragraph if you're already familiar with the proof) This is because, firstly, if $a\in A\cap B$, then $a\in A$ and $a\in B$. But $A$ and $B$ are themselves groups, so it must be the case that $a^{-1}\in A$ and $a^{-1}\in B$ both also hold, i.e. $a^{-1}\in A\cap B$. So $A\cap B$ is closed with respect to inverses. And, secondly, if $y$ and $z$ are in $A\cap B$, then $y$ and $z$ are in $A$ and $y$ and $z$ are in $B$. Again, since $A$ and $B$ are subgroups, $yz\in A$ and $yz\in B$ both must hold so $yz\in A\cap B$ must also hold, i.e. $A\cap B$ is closed with respect to products. Finally, since both $A$ and $B$ are subgroups, $e$ (the identity of $G$) is $\in A$ and $\in B$, so $e\in A\cap B$, making $A\cap B$ non-empty. Combining these three facts, we see that, if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$, $A\cap B$ is also a subgroup of $G$.

We can extend this line of reasoning to any arbitrary number of subgroups so that, if $A_1,A_2,...,$ and $A_n$ is some list of $n$ subgroups of $G$, then $A_1\cap A_2\cap...\cap A_n$ is also a subgroup of $G$.

So the intersection of subgroups of the $G$ in your question that all contain the set $x$ (from your question) will produce a subgroup containing $x$. Since a subgroup is nothing but a group that is a subset of another group (G, in this case), this is a group containing $x$.

Denote this group by $I$ and let $I=\bigcap_{s=1}^r i_s$, where $\{i_1,i_2,...,i_r\}$ is the set of all subgroups containing $x$.

Now, why is this group that contains $x$ generated by $x$?

Let $x=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_m\}$ and denote the group generated by $x$ by $X$.

On one hand, given that all groups are closed with respect to inverses and multiplication, any group, $i_s$ containing $x$ would have to contain $X$. This is because, since $x\subset i_s$, (by definition) $x_1,x_2,...,x_m\in i_s$ so every possible product with elements of $x$ and their inverses (like $x_2^5x_7^{-3}x_3$) must be in $i_s$, i.e. $X$ must be in $i_s$. So $X\subset i_s$ for each $k$ meaning $X\subset \bigcap_{s=1}^r i_s=I$.

On the other hand, notice that that $X$ is, well, a subgroup of $G$ (because each element in $X$ is of the form $x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}...x_m^{k_m}$, the product of any two such elements or the inverse of any such element will also be of this form). And, this ($X$) is a subgroup that contains $x$. So $X$ is in fact equal to one of the $i_s$ (as $X$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $x$). Since, in general, $A\supset A\cap B\;\;$, $X\supset\bigcap_{s=1}^r i_s=I$.

In the end, we have $X\subset I$ and $X\supset I$ which give us $X=I$.

Comment: thank you very very much, the point where is stopped was generation of group X, but now everything is clear for me.